# Getting an error while doing Newtonsoft JSON Deserialize for apostrophe strings in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am getting below exception when I try to execute below snippet code while doing Newtonsoft JSON Deserialize.
Error: After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: s. Path 'Name', line 1, position 14.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   var definition = new { Name = "" };
   string json1 = @"{'Name':'Jame's'}";
   var customer1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json1, definition);
   Console.WriteLine(customer1.Name);
}
```

Comment: The string is `'Jame'`. It's followed by some a non-string character, `n`. You can't have an unescaped single quote inside a single quote string, just as you can't have a double quote inside a double quote string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a single quote, not an apostrophe so it needs to be escaped :

```
string json1 = @"{'Name':'Jame\'s'}";
```

You can't include the string delimiter inside a string without escaping it.

Answer (score 0):

message:
After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: s. Path 'Name', line 1, position 14.

string format is bad :)

change like that

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var definition = new { Name = "" };
        string json1 = "{\"Name\":\"Jame's\"}";
        var customer1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json1, definition);
        Console.WriteLine(customer1.Name);
    }
```